# How to make a button programatically visible in windows phone?

Tags: c#, button, binding, windows-phone

I have a button named **delete**.
I just want to make visible only when certain contions are met,
so how could I do it??

The XAML code for button creation is

```
<Button x:Name="DeleteButton" Content="Delete" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Margin="74,579,0,-9" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="314" FontSize="24"/>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a Visibility property.

You have some ways to do it:

1. Just in code behind you should:

   ```
   if (condition)
   {
       DeleteButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //Also possible to Collapse (hide).
   }
   ```

   The above code should help you make the button invisible and visible respectively.

   *Note:* This is less preferable, it's not dynamic and can cause to duplicates and unnecessary code.
2. The better way and more dynamic is:

   You can make a bool property and to bind the visibility button to it, like this:

   ```
   bool IsVisible { get; set; } //Code behind
   ```

   And in xaml:

   ```
   <!-- Pay attention: The Converter is still not written, follow next steps -->
   <Button x:Name="DeleteButton" 
           Content="Delete"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Margin="74,579,0,-9" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="314" FontSize="24" 
           Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, 
                        Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
   ```

   The converter:

   ```
   public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// Converts a value.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="value">The value produced by the binding source.</param>
       /// <param name="targetType">The type of the binding target property.</param>
       /// <param name="parameter">The converter parameter to use.</param>
       /// <param name="culture">The culture to use in the converter.</param>
       /// <returns>A converted value. Returns Visible if the value is true; otherwise, collapsed.</returns>
       public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       {
           return (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
       }

       public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,CultureInfo culture)
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }
   ```

   And at the resources in xaml you should add the converter so you can access it with the StaticResource:

   ```
   <Application
   x:Class="UI.App"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:converters="using:UI.Converters">

   <converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
   ```

   And then to change the IsVisible property for your need, if true it will be bound to   Visible, if false, it will be collapsed.

   ```
   if (condition)
   {
       IsVisible = true;
   }
   ```

   For more information you should learn: [binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207023%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), [converters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx).

Comment: Can't you just give the IsVisible property a Visibility data type instead of a bool data type?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it also with `XAML` and binding:

In `XAML`:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then in control make sth like:

```
Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

And `IsVisible` is a `bool` property in `ViewModel`.

Comment: +1 but as a note... this only works with .NET 3.0 and higher. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx